# Reading string and storing value by using for

Tags: batch-file

I have a myFile.TXT, let's say like this:

```
PAR2:VAL2
PAR3:VAL3
PAR4:VAL4
PAR5:VAL5
```

Using a Batch, i want to take the values to write them to another file, example grant:

```
MYval_2 VAL2
MYval_3 VAL3
MYval_4 VAL4
MYval_5 VAL5
```

. i tried this:

```
for /f  "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in (myFile.txt) do (
echo MYval_2 %%a >> otherFile.txt
echo MYval_3 %%a >> otherFile.txt
echo MYval_4 %%a >> otherFile.txt
echo MYval_5 %%a >> otherFile.txt
)
```

But as expected, in this way i loop 5 time the file getting this:

```
val_2 VAL2
val_3 VAL2
val_4 VAL2
val_5 VAL2
val_2 VAL3
val_3 VAL3
val_4 VAL3
val_5 VAL3
val_2 VAL4
val_3 VAL4
val_4 VAL4
val_5 VAL4
val_2 VAL5
val_3 VAL5
val_4 VAL5
val_5 VAL5
```

can anyone help me to find out a solution? ^^

Comment: How is the counting? Always consecutive, starting with "2"? If not, what are the rules?

Answer (score 0):

Below you basically set variables based on myFile.txt then you write their value to otherFile.txt

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (myFile.txt) do (
  set str=%%x
  set str=%str::==%
  set "%str%"
)

echo %PAR2% >> otherFile.txt
echo %PAR3% >> otherFile.txt
echo %PAR4% >> otherFile.txt
echo %PAR5% >> otherFile.txt
```

Comment: 1) this doesn't set any variables. 2) `%%x` is not defined anymore with the `echo`-statements.

Comment: Good point. I have done something similar but I used  equal signs in my parm file not colons.

Comment: You need delayed expansion for !str! inside the `for` statement. And you forgot to write the `val_x` to the otherfile.

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes you always want to start with `MYval_2` and count up by one for each line.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET COUNT=2
FOR /F  "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a IN (myFile.txt) DO (
  ECHO MYval_!COUNT! %%a>>otherFile.txt
  SET /A COUNT+=1
)
```